# Pentahoo - configure dynamic database name

Tags: pentaho-spoon

I want to use a table in penthaoo spoon. The table exists, I double-checked it. My connection to database configuration uses dynamics variables, so it shows an error when configuring table exists step. You can see the error below:

**Transformation**
[image: Transformation]

**Error**

[image: Error]

Comment: Please post the relevant configuration and the error.

Comment: help plz !!!!!!

Comment: Fixed grammar. Highlighted the problem in the title.